# How to get label in cells in table to go on to next line instead of getting cut off screen? (xcode 8)

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

So basically I am loading text from an array into cells in a table view, but instead of going on to the next line like I want, the inputted text labels get cut off the screen in the single cell. I looked online and it said to set numberOfLines to 0 and lineBreakMode to NSLineBreakingByWordWrapping, but it isn't working. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "homeSeries", for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel?.text = dataArrayRelease[indexPath.row] + " " + dataArraySeries[indexPath.row] + " by " + dataArrayGroup[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping

    return cell
}
```

Comment: add the  code of heightForRow method

Comment: checkout my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `cellForRowAt` method code is proper. you need to do some stuff related row height.
Set up your tableview row height as `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in `viewDidLoad()` method.

```
yourTableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
yourTableview.estimatedRowHeight = 44
```

**OR**

you can add Bellow `UITableViewDelegate` method in your Controller

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 44
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

Comment: That will not work until @ethan gives proper constraints , Please add it to your answer if needed

Comment: Wait so what should be put in the section "yourTableview"?

Comment: @Mike Alter, as per my knowledge if you are using UITableViewCell direct than to can't set constraints

Comment: @ethan  "yourTableview" =  your tableview object name OR IBOutlets name

Comment: I see, so I did all that but it still says "Use of unresolved identifier NSLineBreakByWordWrapping" and gives me an error.

Comment: @Ethan Replace this cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

Comment: @ethan feel glad to help you.