# Cells in UITableView overlapping. Many cells in one place

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, swift3, overlapping

I'm trying to make table view with random numbers of labels in. Everything is working till I try too scroll it. Than many some of cells appear in one place. It looks like this:

[Screen from simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BaF1.jpg)

To make random row height in viewDidLoad() I put this:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

The code going to write randoms number of labels with random number of lines is here:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {   
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HarvestPlan", for: indexPath) as! HarvestPlanCell
    let currentSpecies = harvestPlan[indexPath.row]

    var kindLabels = [UILabel]()
    cell.kindsNamesView.bounds.size.width = 100
    for kind in currentSpecies.kinds {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.text = kind.fullName
        label.bounds.size.width = 100
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.bounds.size.width = 100
        cell.kindsNamesView.addSubview(label)
        kindLabels.append(label)
    }



    var previous: UILabel!

    for label in kindLabels {
        label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: label.bounds.height).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.kindsNamesView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

        if previous == nil {
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.kindsNamesView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        }

        if previous != nil {
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previous.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        }

        if label == kindLabels.last {
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.kindsNamesView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        }

        previous = label
    }

    return cell
```

Someone have some idea how to repair it? I'm looking for answer since one week and I did't find anything about it...

Comment: cells are reused.  You are adding labels each time you get the cell, but not removing any old labels.  You probably shouldn't add the labels directly in `cellForRow(at:)` anyway; it should be a method in your UITableViewCell subclass.  You can need to keep track of the labels that are added and remove them in `prepareForReuse`

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43133261/how-to-get-label-in-cells-in-table-to-go-on-to-next-line-instead-of-getting-cut/43133311#43133311

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you! 'prepareForReuse' was this what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Paulw11, prepareForReuse was this what I was looking for. If someone have similar problem, the answer is code below added to UITableViewCell:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    for view in kindsNames.subviews { //take all subviews from your view
        view.removeFromSuperview() //delete it from you view
    }
}
```

Cheers